# i couldn't do a simple select top 1 * from table, and nothing with one table, which posible problems could be?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, transactions

i got this error

> timeout value expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion
>   of the operation or the server is not responding

i have a process, which do inserts and update at night, another process
 which does query at nights too, (etl or dts) at sql server 2005 so, now we need to do a query to this table, and this doesn't work, i want to run my process again,  and this never finish, and noneone can do a query to this table, (another tables could do) users commented me, yesterday they could do, but today, they coulden't is it posible, my process is execute at night has never finished, and it let a begin transaccion open?
how can i to be sure of this? and close it from ssms ?

this is not a problem of permissions we could do queries and inserts/updates yesterday.

it happens only with one table.

Comment: Check for locks with sp_lock2.

Comment: how do i use it? sp_lock2 tablename?

Comment: @zimdanen i have see i need create it, but we dont have permission for create at this database only on test, but this database we cant

Comment: Try just sp_lock.  Or use [this](http://utilicode.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/find-all-blocked-commands/) to look for blocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table (nolock)
```

Does that return results?  If so, sounds like a locking issue..